# Skip the Login View Controller when user is already login in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a home screen with a button on it , when we click a button it shows a login screen, the user get login through phone number , if user enter number which is not register before it shows button on screen to go to the register form screen, Now i'm trying that if user is already login then whenever it opens the app the login screen should not be seen , it should directly go to the next screen which comes after login, if user is not login before then it should show login screen. My code is,

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

UIStoryboard *storyBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

if([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"login"])
{
    // So, here user already login then set your root view controller, let's say `SecondViewController``
    HomeViewController *secondViewController = [storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"HomeViewController"];
    // then set your root view controller
    self.window.rootViewController = secondViewController;
} else
{
    // It means you need to your root view controller is your login view controller, so let's create it
    RegisterViewController  *loginViewController= [storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"RegisterD"];
    self.window.rootViewController = loginViewController;
}
// Override point for customization after application launch.
return YES;
```

}

Comment: what you set in `@"login"` ? means which value set in that ?

Comment: you can store the state, ie. if user is logged in or not in `NSUserDefaults` and redirect accordingly.

Comment: In @"login" if user is login and in @"register" if user want to register. Its NSUserDefault value. @NiravKotecha

Comment: How can i redirect it? @Priyal

Comment: @Oneeb is it resolved?

Comment: No it is not. @Priyal

Answer (score 1):

use boolforkey insted value for key as

```
 [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"login"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set current user login state using NSUserDefault.
On next app launch, on home view controller, When you click on that button, before loading login screen, check user login status. If it is true, then load next screen directly, and if not redirect to the login screen.

```
func loginButtonOnHomeScreen(sender:UIButton){
  let loginState = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "Login")
        var VC:UIViewController
        if loginState == true{
             VC = (self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "NextScreen"))!
        }else{
            VC = (self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LoginScreen"))!
        }
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(VC, animated: true)
}
```

Hope this will help

edit 
n Objective C

```
 BOOL loginState = [[NSUserDefaults  standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"Login"];
    UIViewController *VC;
    if (loginState == true){
        VC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"NextScreen"];
    }else{
        VC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LoginScreen"];
    }
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:VC animated:true];
```

Comment: I'm using objective-c can u write this code in objective c? @KavyaKavita

Comment: I have added Objective C version in above answer.

Comment: let me try. @KabyaKavita

Comment: we have to write anything in Appdelegate.m ?@KavyaKavita

Comment: If in both case you want homescreen as your landing screen then no. Remove those conditions and use only this   HomeViewController *secondViewController = [storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"HomeViewController"];
    // then set your root view controller
    self.window.rootViewController = secondViewController;

Comment: Yup i want that if user is login or not first i have to show home screen , than after clicking the button there we have to skip login screen if its login and if not than show the login screen. @KavyaKavita

Comment: Im writing this in button - (IBAction)History:(id)sender {
    NSString *savedValue = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
                            stringForKey:@"login"];
    if ([savedValue isEqualToString:@"login"]) {
        DetailsViewController *presales = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"detail"];
  [self.navigationController pushViewController:presales animated:YES]; }else{ RegisterViewController *presales = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Register"]; [self.navigationController pushViewController:presales animated:YES];}

Comment: No its not working.Not even its going to any screen. @KavyaKavita

Comment: Can you add your code where you are saving your login status?

Comment: in my login view controller class i'm saving it as this ,   [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:value forKey:@"login"];
          [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize]; @KavyaKavita

Comment: What is this value ? is it a string or bool value

Comment: Value is the response coming from API and its a string. @KavyaKavita

Comment: okay instead of that you can directly use static string "login", which you are using while checking condition .  [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@"login" forKey:@"login"]; [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

Comment: So what to write now? @KavyaKavita

Comment: on login success add this
[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@"login" forKey:@"login"]; [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

Comment: Its showing a blank black screen after writing this code. @KavyaKavita

Comment: Debug your code and check which condition is executing, also check if have navigation controller. If not, then you need to do some changes in appdelegate.

Answer (score 0):

When user login/register successfully set

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"login"];
```

When user logout at that time remove from NSUserDefaults or set false

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] removeObjectForKey:@"login"];
```

OR

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:FALSE forKey:@"login"];
```

you can check user is already login or not in appDelegate file or any other your suitable screen

```
if([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"login"])
{
    //YES Already Login
    NextController *nextVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"NextController"];
}
else
{
    //NOT Login
    LoginController *loginVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LoginController"];
}
```

Comment: How can i go to the next screen directly from home when user is login, through ur code could this happen that login screen skips when user is login? @Nirav Kotecha

Comment: you can use segue to go next screen directly from home controller.. `[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segueToNextController" sender:self];` **"segueToNextController"** is identifier so same name also give in storyboard.

Comment: Okay let me try it. @NiravKotecha

Comment: No bro its not taking me to second screen its coming again and again to login screen. @Nirav Kotecha

Comment: have you written `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"login"];` in your controller ?

Comment: `if([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"login"])` this condition check in login controller --> viewDidLoad Method

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/euutr5nn2oqs1to/demo.zip?dl=0 please check it this demo. you will better understand in this demo

Comment: Its showing a blank black screen after writing this code. @Nirav Kotecha

Comment: also you can download demo from above link where you can see code and understand with practically

Comment: same as u written above . @Nirav Kotecha

Comment: [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"login"]; this line in login screen and this if([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"login"])
{
    //YES Already Login
    NextController *nextVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"NextController"];
}
else
{
    //NOT Login
    LoginController *loginVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LoginController"];
} in button action. @Nirva Kotecha

Comment: when login success after you set YES and if condition check in first controller / login controller

Comment: let say we have 2 controller. 1. ViewController and 2. NextViewController ViewController have login button and NextViewController have logout button. so we first checked in ViewController that is login or not ? if login than it will go to NextViewController otherwise its remain same in ViewController. after click on login button it will redirect to NextViewController and set yes into that. on logout button set no.

Comment: Let me explain you the scenario that i have Home VC in which i have a button on which when i click it takes us to Login VC there we got login through phone number, If response comes 1 it means u r login now, and if response comes 0 an alert view appear in which there is a button when we click on it it takes us to Registration VC. @Nirav Kotecha

Comment: Now i want that when user is not login first as usual Home VC should appear and when click the button it should go to Login VC and If user is login before than first Home VC should appear again and when it click the button it should directly go to the Next VC skipping the Login VC. Thats what i want, if there is any problem while getting this i'm here to explain more. @Nirav Kotecha

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 ViewController (LoginVC and HomeVC),
First write bellow code in "LoginVC"

```
if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"loggedIn"]){

   nslog(@"Success"};
 }
else{
    nslog(@"Login Agin")
 }
```

Second code write in HomeVC(This After login)

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{

  [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setBool:YES forKey:@"loggedIn"];
}
```